# Rails 3 how to render .json.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on migrating a rather big project to Rails 3.

Here's my controller action:

```
def recent
  @account = Account.find(session[:account_id])
  render :layout => false
end
```

Here's my recent.json.erb file

```
formatted_account = 
{
  :code = 1,
  :id = @account.id,
  :prefix = 2
}   
formatted_account.to_json()
```

I'm using jQuery.getJSON to get this data, when I get the response, this is what I get:

```
[{&quot;code&quot;:1,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1 &quot;prefix&quot;:2}]
```

Instead of

```
[{code:1, id:1, prefix:2}]
```

I had to use safe_html in some other pieces of code to solve escaping issues like this but in this case I can't figure out how to solve without getting rid of the .json.rb file and rendering a json object in a proper way.

Answer (score 1):

html_safe did the trick:

```
formatted_account = 
{
  :code = 1,
  :id = @account.id,
  :prefix = 2
}   
formatted_account.to_json.html_safe
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build up json from a template you'll need to use some kind of builder as ERB won't really cut it.

JBuilder comes commented out in a fresh Rails 3.2 Gemfile. Haven't used it myself but it seems well thought out with a clean DSL. There's also a list of links at the bottom of the README on the JBuilder github page.

RABL is another tool for building JSON, as well as supporting multiple other formats.

[JBuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder)
[RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl)